# How to use "to be"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I saw a quote that goes, "Here's to new beginnings. To all we can't see yet. Surrendering to who we're just about ***to be***."

Why did they add "**to be**" at the end of the sentence?

Answer (score 2):

"Be" is one of the fundamental words with many meanings.

Here is roughly synonymous with "become" or "change into".  This is a "[toast](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/toast_2)" (The start, "here's to..." is "here is a drink to wish...") and the toast is dedicated "new beginnings". The last part suggests that you let your "future" control your "present". "The person you are about to be" is "you, in the future".